# Agregar quitar divs con atributos auto incrementable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Necesito agregar controles a un formulario con un botón de `+`, pero con máximo 8 controles. De momento me funciona agregar, pero si quito y vuelvo a agregar ya no toma el numero que eliminé.

Digamos que agregué 6 controles pero quité uno ,se queda en 5, luego agrego otra vez, pero se brinca al 7, todos estros controles se envían a un backend [php](/questions/tagged/php).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
        Replica
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="divPadre">
    </div>
    <button onclick="mostrarMas(this)">
        Mostrar más
    </button>
    <button onclick="mostrarMenos()">
        Mostrar menos
    </button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var numeroDiv = '1';
      function mostrarMas(element){
        let divsNuevos = `<div> Soy el pago ${numeroDiv++} <input type="text" name="pago${name++}" placeholder="Username"></div>`;
        $('#divPadre').append(divsNuevos);  
        if($('#divPadre').children('div').length >= 8){    
          $(element).prop('disabled', true);
          alert("Ya no puedes agregar más");
        }
      }
      function mostrarMenos(){
        $('#divPadre').children('div').last().remove();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que quieres esto:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>
      Replica
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="divPadre">
    </div>
    <button onclick="mostrarMas(this)">
      Mostrar más
    </button>
    <button onclick="mostrarMenos()">
      Mostrar menos
    </button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var numeroDiv = '1';

    function mostrarMas(element) {

      let divsNuevos = `<div> Soy el pago ${numeroDiv++} <input type="text" name="pago${name++}" placeholder="Username"></div>`;
      $('#divPadre').append(divsNuevos);

      if ($('#divPadre').children('div').length >= 8) {
        $(element).prop('disabled', true);
        alert("Ya no puedes agregar más");
      }
    }

    function mostrarMenos() {
      $('#divPadre').children('div').last().remove();
      numeroDiv--
      name--
    }
    </script>
  </body>
```

**Explicación**

Básicamente se trata de sustraer una unidad del valor de las variables `numeroDiv` y `name` cada vez que eliminas un hijo, agregando estas dos líneas a la función `mostrarMenos()`:

```
numeroDiv--
name--
```

Comment: Si puse eso de  numeroDiv-- pero con -1, solo una correción no hay variable de name entonces seguira contando sin restar

Comment: Bueno, quizas no esta definida a modo global, cierto, pero aquí parecia que la querias usar y no me fijé en que no la usas realmente:  `name="pago${name++}"`

Comment: Sí, digo igual por si a alguien le sirve mi comentario, ¿Puedes explicarme bien el uso de ${} en los atributos del tag?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835362/what-does-dollar-sign-and-curly-braces-mean-in-a-string-in-javascript por si alguien en el futuro le interesa

Comment: Aquí lo explica más académicamente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals